# How to Parse JSON with more than one array in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, swift2

I'm new in swift language, newbie question but I have to ask cause my mind is little bit confused about dictionary and array usage here, I got a json like this;

```
 {
  "MainPageLast": [
  {},
  {}..
  ],
  "MainPageSport": [
  {},
  {}..
  ],
  "MainPageEco": [
  {},
  {}..
  ],
  "MainPagePol": [
  {},
  {}..
  ]
}
```

I made base class which includes all of these arrays as dictionary like this;

```
public class func modelsFromDictionaryArray(array:NSArray) -> [Json4Swift_Base]
    {
        var models:[Json4Swift_Base] = []
        for item in array
        {
            models.append(Json4Swift_Base(dictionary: item as! NSDictionary)!)
        }
        return models
    }

required public init?(dictionary: NSDictionary) {

        if (dictionary["MainPageLast"] != nil) { mainPageLast = MainPageLast.modelsFromDictionaryArray(dictionary["MainPageLast"] as! NSArray) }
        if (dictionary["MainPageSport"] != nil) { mainPageSport = MainPageSport.modelsFromDictionaryArray(dictionary["MainPageSport"] as! NSArray) }
        if (dictionary["MainPageEco"] != nil) { mainPageEco = MainPageEco.modelsFromDictionaryArray(dictionary["MainPageEco"] as! NSArray) }
        if (dictionary["MainPagePol"] != nil) { mainPagePol = MainPagePol.modelsFromDictionaryArray(dictionary["MainPagePol"] as! NSArray) }
    }

public func dictionaryRepresentation() -> NSDictionary {

        let dictionary = NSMutableDictionary()


        return dictionary
    }
```

And I try to get data and try to parse and want to see the returning data in debug screen;

```
func loadHeadline(completion : ((AnyObject) -> Void)!) {

        let urlString = "http://myapiurl."

        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let newsUrl = NSURL(string: urlString)

        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(newsUrl!, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in

            do {
                let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

                var models:[Json4Swift_Base] = []
                for item in jsonData
                {
                    models.append(Json4Swift_Base(dictionary: item as NSDictionary)!)
                }

            } catch let error as NSError{
                print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }

        })
        task.resume()
    }
```

I know I need to reach each [0], [1]... items one by one in Json4Swift_Base class but I really could not figure how to.

This Exception throws when I try to

```
models.append

exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)
```

Now, which way should I follow or what to do to get and put all data in one.

Thanks in advice..

Comment: do you have a sample dataset of the json you would handle? I can try it in a playground

Comment: @Scriptable can you check the first code block please. Do you need more info about it ? Thanks.

Comment: it would be handy to know what is in the array too i think

Comment: Since you are new to Swift, get used to the native collection types `Array` and `Dictionary` which suit the strong type system of Swift much more than the Foundation equivalents.

Comment: @vadian thanks for the advice but I need to figure out how to handle that..

Comment: @Scriptable there are properties in arrays. But the main structure is that, 4 different arrays and each array has nodes, nodes have properties etc.. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let jsonData = try NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe)
                do {
                    let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSArray

                    if let allData = jsonResult[0] as? NSDictionary {
                        let header = allData.objectForKey("MainPageMansetData")
                        let magazine = allData.objectForKey("MainPageMagazineData")
                        let sports = allData.objectForKey("MainPageSportsData")
                        let articles = allData.objectForKey("MainPageOtherArticles")

                        print("\(header) \n \(magazine) \n \(sports) \n \(articles)")
                    }
                } catch {}
```

Comment: Can you check the updated code block. In Json4Swift_Base, there is also code block like that at the end. So it is dictionary. I tried your answer also and xcode says; "cannot covert value type anyobject to nsdictionary in coercion.."